# Motor struggles as front passenger tires pulls and seems to lock up

Tags: wheels, jeep, grand-cherokee, power-loss

1996 jeep grand Cherokee v8 4x4 we have changed the calipers thinking that it was locking up but on driving it again we get the same issue. After driving about 3-5 miles you get a lot of walking from the vehicle then go another mile or so and all the gauges seem to drag and feels like the motor is working hard to get that passenger front tire to move and then you hear a few noises and the vehicle walks and pulls if you drive it a bit farther it slowly seems to work it's way out. You smell what is either hot metal or rubber I can't quite distinguish but I also seem to loose oil pressure with the motor seemingly working hard. The tire doesn't lock up and everything else looked good when we changed the calipers could this be more with the motor or transfer case?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Say more about the tire. Which tire? Is it always the same tire? Why do you think the tire is hard to move? Is the tire unusually hot to the touch? Sounds like a brake issue to me: bad caliper, bad brake lines: at 24 years, they're too old to trust and could be failing internally.

Comment: Front passenger tire, it always feel to be coming from that tire. Have checked and doesn't seem to be hot. I changed rotor pads and caliper. It honestly feels like once the motor starts seemingly working harder to move the tire I can hear noise from the tire area and feels like it's gone flat on me, that is the sensation I get from the steering wheel.

Comment: Is it locked in 4*4? Sounds like it is getting wound up...